# A problem on monotonicity rule for the ratio of two Maclaurin power series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-series

In the paper [1] below, a monotonicity rule for the ratio of two Maclaurin power series was presented as follow.

> Let $a_k$ and $b_k$ for $k\in\{0\}\cup\mathbb{N}$ be real numbers and
> the power series \begin{equation*} A(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\quad\text{and}\quad B(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kx^k
> \end{equation*}
> be convergent on $(-R,R)$ for some $R>0$. If $b_k>0$
> and the ratio $\frac{a_k}{b_k}$ is increasing for $k\ge0$, then the function $\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}$ is also increasing on $(0,R)$.

There are many monotonicity rules for ratios of two functions, two Laplace transforms, two functional series, and the like. See, for example, the papers [2, 3, 4] listed below.

My problem is:

> About the above monotonicity rule for the ratio of two Maclaurin power
> series $A(x)$ and $B(x)$, is there any related monotonicity conclusion on the left
> semi-half interval $(-R,0)$? In other words, under what conditions
> about the sequence $\frac{a_k}{b_k}$ for $k\ge0$, the function
> $\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}$ is monotonic on $(-R,0)$?

My problem should be revised as follows:

> About the above monotonicity rule for the ratio of two Maclaurin power
> series $A(x)$ and $B(x)$, is there any related monotonicity result on
> the left semi-half interval $(-R,0)$? In other words, under same
> conditions on the sequences $a_k$, $b_k$, and $\frac{a_k}{b_k}$ for
> $k\ge0$, is there any monotonicity result of the function
> $\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}$ on $(-R,0)$?

References

1. M. Biernacki and J. Krzyz, *On the monotonity of certain functionals in the theory of analytic functions*, Ann. Univ. Mariae Curie-Sklodowska Sect. A **9** (1955), 135--147 (1957).
2. Z.-H. Yang, Y.-M. Chu, and M.-K. Wang, *Monotonicity criterion for the quotient of power series with applications*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **428** (2015), no. 1, 587--604; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2015.03.043.
3. Feng Qi and Yong-Hong Yao, *Increasing property and logarithmic convexity concerning Dirichlet beta function, Euler numbers, and their ratios*, Hacettepe Journal of Mathematics and Statistics **52** (2023), no. 1, 17--22; available online at https://doi.org/10.15672/hujms.1099250.
4. I. Pinelis, *On L'Hospital-type rules for monotonicity*, J. Inequal. Pure Appl. Math. **7** (2006), no. 2, Article 40, 19 pages; available online at https://emis.de/journals/JIPAM/article657.html.

Comment: @IosifPinelis  Dear Professor Pinelis, you are an expert on monotonicity rules, could you please help me find a solution to this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Of course, you can trivially do the reflection $x\leftrightarrow-x$ and at the same time change the condition $b_k>0$ to $(-1)^kb_k>0$, to get the result for $(-R,0)$ from that for $(0,R)$. However, I do not think that one can say anything useful in general for $(0,R)$ without the condition $b_k>0$. So then, one can hardly say anything useful in general for $(-R,0)$ without the condition $(-1)^b_k>0$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis  Thank you for your answer to my question. Could you please give a solution to my revised problem above?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that such results exist and would be surprised if they do exist.